# How does Sonar calculate the cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: java, sonarqube, graph-theory, checkstyle, cyclomatic-complexity

Sonar gives me the following cyclomatic complexity number : 22.

For the following program :

```
private static SomeDto checkSomething(AnotherDto anotherDto, String reference)
{
SomeDto someDto = new SomeDto();

// condition 1
if (!someDto.getA())
    return new SomeDto("bla1", "blabla");

// condition 2
if (someDto.getName2() == null || checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))
    return new SomeDto("bla2", "blabla");

// condition 3
if (someDto.getName3() == null || checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))
    return new SomeDto("bla3", "blabla");

// condition 4
if (someDto.getName4() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))
    return new SomeDto("bla4", "blabla");

// condition 5
if (someDto.getName5() == null || checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))
    return new SomeDto("bla5", "blabla");

// condition 6
if (someDto.getName6() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))
    return new SomeDto("bla6", "blabla");

// condition 7
if (someDto.getName7() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))
    return new SomeDto("bla7", "blabla");

// condition 8
if (someDto.getName8() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))
    return new SomeDto("bla8", "blabla");

// condition 9
if (someDto.getName9() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))
    return new SomeDto("bla9", "blabla");

// condition 10
if (someDto.getName10() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))
    return new SomeDto("bla10", "blabla");

// condition 11
if (someDto.getName11() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))
    return new SomeDto("bla11", "blabla");

return someDto;
}
```

The issue i get is the following :

*"The Cyclomatic Complexity of this method "checkSomething" is 22 which is greater than 12 authorized.*"

My question is :
considering the McCabe formula V(G) = E - N + 2, how does Sonar reach the number of 22 ?

Where :

E = number of edges

N = number of nodes

How many edges and nodes are there in this method  ?
What is the control flow for this method ?

We're on SonarQube Version 6.3 (build 19869).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the name and version of the analyzer in question

Comment: could you post a concrete `if (condition*)` ?

Comment: Yes.                                                                                                                     `if (anotherDto.getName() == null || !checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))
            return new SomeDto("bla10", "blabla");`

Comment: I edited the code of the method. The conditions (ifs) contain || or && operands, except the first one.

Answer (score 7):

The SonarQube [documentation for the latest version](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/metric-definitions/) clearly states how it calculates the Cyclomatic Complexity:

> Complexity (complexity) It is the Cyclomatic Complexity calculated
>   based on the number of paths through the code. Whenever the control
>   flow of a function splits, the complexity counter gets incremented by
>   one. Each function has a minimum complexity of 1. This calculation
>   varies slightly by language because keywords and functionalities do.

And if you open the "Language-specific details" underneath that paragraph, the Java line reads as follows.

> Keywords incrementing the complexity: if, for, while, case, catch,
>   throw, &&, ||, ?

Since the OP was using version 6.3 by the time of the question, I also checked the [documentation for the oldest version](https://docs.sonarqube.org/6.7/Metrics-Complexity.html) that I could find, which is 6.7. By then, the calculation was slightly different.

> Keywords incrementing the complexity: if, for, while, case, catch,
>   throw, return (that is not the last statement of a method), &&, ||, ?
>
> Notes:
>
> else, default, and finally keywords do not increment the complexity.
>
> a simple method with a switch statement and a huge block of case
>   statements can have a surprisingly high complexity value (still it has
>   the same value when converting a switch block to an equivalent
>   sequence of if statements).
>
> Example: the following method has a complexity of 5

```
public void process(Car myCar){          // +1
    if(myCar.isNotMine()){               // +1
         return;                         // +1
    }
    car.paint("red");
    car.changeWheel();
    while(car.hasGazol() && car.getDriver().isNotStressed()){   // +2
         car.drive();
    }
    return; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, after further investigation and according to this [link](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_metrics.html#CyclomaticComplexity) (checkstyle tool), I have concluded that the McCabe formula is not really applied to calculate the cyclomatic complexity in a Java program.

> The complexity is equal to the number of decision points + 1 Decision points: if, while , do, for, ?:, catch , switch, case statements, and operators && and || in the body of target.

So if I apply this rule to the previous sample code :

```
private static SomeDto checkSomething(AnotherDto anotherDto, String reference)  // 1
{
SomeDto someDto = new SomeDto();

// condition 1
if (!someDto.getA())                                                             // 2
return new SomeDto("bla1", "blabla");

// condition 2
if (someDto.getName2() == null || checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))             // 4
return new SomeDto("bla2", "blabla");

// condition 3
if (someDto.getName3() == null || checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))             // 6
return new SomeDto("bla3", "blabla");

// condition 4
if (someDto.getName4() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))             // 8
return new SomeDto("bla4", "blabla");

// condition 5
if (someDto.getName5() == null || checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))              // 10
return new SomeDto("bla5", "blabla");

// condition 6
if (someDto.getName6() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))              // 12
return new SomeDto("bla6", "blabla");

// condition 7
if (someDto.getName7() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))              // 14
return new SomeDto("bla7", "blabla");

// condition 8
if (someDto.getName8() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))              // 16
return new SomeDto("bla8", "blabla");

// condition 9
if (someDto.getName9() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))              // 18
return new SomeDto("bla9", "blabla");

// condition 10
if (someDto.getName10() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))             // 20
return new SomeDto("bla10", "blabla");

// condition 11
if (someDto.getName11() == null && checkSurName(anotherDto.getName()))             // 22
return new SomeDto("bla11", "blabla");

return someDto;
}
```

Correct me if i am wrong.
Shouldn't the return statements (except the one that is the last statement of the method) be taken into account at least ?

Anyways, the result number of 22 makes sense. This method has an awful number of successive "if" conditions and something should be done about it to improve its maintainability.

Comment: Yse. Sonar DO NOT use Cyclomatic Complexity，it has it's own way.

 https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metrics+-+Complexity

Comment: I guess it's 2 for an "if" statement (if + else), 11 if statement * 2 for each if = 22

Comment: @LucasLiu in fact it does as it is stated in the documentation link that you shared: "Complexity (complexity)
It is the Cyclomatic Complexity calculated based on the number of paths through the code. "